# Hugo : how to display in section page a list of subsections

Tags: hugo

This will be an easy question, but I have spent already a lot of time, and I can't find a definitive answer. Here is the current state of my blog : https://brucou.github.io/

In `Projects`, I have the following directory structure :

```
Projects
  Component combinators
  Trees and forests
  Circuitry
```

In my project page (`/projects/`), I want to display a list of the corresponding sub-folders, i.e. `Component combinators`, `Trees and forests`, etc. with the corresponding permalinks.

I have this code in `/layouts/projects/list.html`

```
<ul>
  {{ template "section-tree-nav" .Site.Home }}
</ul>
{{ define "section-tree-nav" }}
  {{ range .Sections}}
    <li>{{ .Title }}
        <ul>
            {{ range .Pages }}
            <li><a href="{{ .RelPermalink}}">{{ .Title }}</a></li>
            {{ end }}
            <ul>
                {{ template "section-tree-nav" . }}
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </li>
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

Currently this code displays in the projects page, a directory tree, i.e for example :

```
Posts
  Reactive programming : a component-based approach
  A componentization model for cyclejs
  Componentization against complexity
  User interfaces as reactive systems
Projects
  Component combinators
```

My question is :

- how to display only the `Projects` directory content? or basically how to do an `if` on the title?content? of the projects directory?

That is I want only this displayed in the projects page :

```
  Component combinators
  Trees and forests
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it this way :

```
{{ partial "header" . }}

<article>
    <header>
        {{ partial "title" . }}
        {{ with .Content }}{{.}}{{ end }}
    </header>

    {{ if (eq $.Parent.Title "Projects") }}
      <ul class="no-bullet">
          {{ range .Paginator.Pages }}
          {{ partial "li" . }}
          {{ end }}
      </ul>
      {{ partial "paginator" . }}
    {{ else }}
      {{ range (where .Site.Pages "Section" "projects") }}
        <ul class="no-bullet">
            {{ range .Sections }}
            <li>
                <span><time datetime="{{.Date}}">{{ .Date.Format .Site.Params.DateFmt }}</time></span>
                <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ .Title }}</a>
            </li>
            {{ end }}
        </ul>
      {{ end }}
    {{ end }}

</article>
{{ partial "footer" . }}


{{/* keep the / right next to the parenthesis */}}
{{/* printf "%#v" $.CurrentSection.Title */}}
{{/* printf "%#v" (eq $.Parent.Title "Projects") */}}
```

Basically, we branch on the level of the hierarchy. If at top level, then we display the directories (stored in `.Sections`), if not, we display the pages.